# How to conditions in multiple associated table in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i am facing one problem. Can anyone help me
Firstly I have two Models

1)User.php

```
enter code here
public function listings(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Listing','user_id')
          ->with("topservices");
}
```

Now i have Listing Model

2) (Listing.php)

```
enter code here
public function topservices(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Sellerprofile','list_id');
}
```

Now i have one function

```
enter code here
public function nails(){
    $users = DB::table('users')
        ->where(['service_name'=>"Seller"])
        ->get();
    $users = json_decode(json_encode($users),true);
    foreach($users as $alluser){
        $ids[] = $alluser['id']; 
    }
    if(!empty($ids)){
            $allData = User::with('listings')->whereIn('id',$ids)->get();
            $allData = json_decode(json_encode($allData),true);
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($allData); die; ///when i print this array it gives me below output

    } 
    $title = "Nails";
    return view("listings.listing",['allData'=>$allData,'title'=>$title]);
}
```

Output:

```
enter code here
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => Mr
        [firstname] => kunal
        [email] => kunal@gmail.comsc
        [listings] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 1
                [type] => premimum
                [business_name] => kunal
                [topservices] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 5
                                [service_id] => 1
                                [list_id] => 1
                                [name] => Acrylic 
                                [duration] => 10mins
                                [price] => 10
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 6
                                [service_id] => 2
                                [list_id] => 1
                                [name] => Hair Top
                                [duration] => 30mins
                                [price] => 20
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 7
                                [service_id] => 3
                                [list_id] => 1
                                [name] => Skin Care Top
                                [duration] => 1hr-30mins
                                [price] => 30
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 8
                                [service_id] => 4
                                [list_id] => 1
                                [name] => Massage Top
                                [duration] => 20mins
                                [price] => 50
                            )

                    )
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => Mr
        [firstname] => kunal
        [email] => kunal@gmail.comsdsfd
        [listings] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [user_id] => 2
                [type] => premimum
                [topservices] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 9
                                [service_id] => 6
                                [list_id] => 2
                                [name] => Acrylic 
                                [duration] => 30mins
                                [price] => 10
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 10
                                [service_id] => 6
                                [list_id] => 2
                                [name] => Powder gel nails 
                                [duration] => 45mins
                                [price] => 20
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 11
                                [service_id] => 6
                                [list_id] => 2
                                [name] => Polish change
                                [duration] => 10mins
                                [price] => 25
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 12
                                [service_id] => 6
                                [list_id] => 2
                                [name] => Hand design
                                [duration] => 2hrs
                                [price] => 100
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 13
                                [service_id] => 7
                                [list_id] => 2
                                [name] => Hair Top
                                [duration] => 30mins
                                [price] => 200
                            )

                    )
            )

    )
)
```

Now you seen above output there is Topservices array i want all those array under topservices whose price is greater than= 10 and less than equal to 30 
My expected Output is:-

```
enter code here
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => Mr
        [firstname] => kunal
        [email] => kunal@gmail.comsc
        [listings] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 1
                [type] => premimum
                [business_name] => kunal
                [topservices] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 5
                                [service_id] => 1
                                [list_id] => 1
                                [name] => Acrylic 
                                [duration] => 10mins
                                [price] => 10
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 6
                                [service_id] => 2
                                [list_id] => 1
                                [name] => Hair Top
                                [duration] => 30mins
                                [price] => 20
                            )
                    )
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => Mr
        [firstname] => kunal
        [email] => kunal@gmail.comsdsfd
        [listings] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [user_id] => 2
                [type] => premimum
                [topservices] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 9
                                [service_id] => 6
                                [list_id] => 2
                                [name] => Acrylic 
                                [duration] => 30mins
                                [price] => 10
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 10
                                [service_id] => 6
                                [list_id] => 2
                                [name] => Powder gel nails 
                                [duration] => 45mins
                                [price] => 20
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 11
                                [service_id] => 6
                                [list_id] => 2
                                [name] => Polish change
                                [duration] => 10mins
                                [price] => 25
                            )

                    )
            )

    )
)
```

Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance What i do in nails function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i found the solution of my own.

```
enter code here
$allData = User::with(['listings.topservices'=>function($query){
           $query->whereBetween('price',[10,350]);
           }])
           ->whereIn('id',$ids)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your method to include the condition.
You can use `whereBetween` method:

```
public function listings($lowerPriceLimit = null,$upperPriceLimit = null){
    $query = $this->hasOne('App\Listing','user_id');
    if($lowerPriceLimit != null &&  $upperPriceLimit != null)
        $query = $query->with(["topservices"=>function($q) use($lowerPriceLimit,$upperPriceLimit ){
                            $q->whereBetween('price',[$lowerPriceLimit,$upperPriceLimit]);
                        }]);
    else
        $query->with("topservices");
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Not working @jaysingkar its giving me error (explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given)  :(

Comment: you use price in whereBetween price column is not in listing table it is in topservices Hope you understand it gives me error (Unknown column 'price' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `listings` where `listings`.`user_id` in (1, 2) and `price` between 10 and 30))